# why in UINavigation bar, push and pop are not working proper according (XCode5) ios sdk-7?

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, pushviewcontroller, ios7, popviewcontroller

i am getting these error:

nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar.

Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions.

I am trying to push one view controller to another one.i am getting following issues:

1. on that it is not showing title while i gave it in view will appear.
2. if i turn back it is now showing me blank view (transparent) having that title what i was not able to see in previous view controller.
3. if now i again turn back, it is showing me right sequence of titles as i am popping but without content.i mean blank (transparent).*

Comment: iOS 7 is under NDA. So apple docs and appl forums will be the best place for asking this question

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, it turned out to be that I was making two repeated calls to `pushViewController:`, which presented the same View Controller twice, and when I was going to pop it, the content would stay but the navigation bar would do the animation. I was having this message on the log *'Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for ...'*

Answer (score 0):

Xcode_5_developer_preview_6 (beta5) is the answer for this. i just installed it. they have resolved this issue which was in Xcode_5_developer_preview beta4.